# Get World Coordinates of CGPoint in ARSCNView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, arscnview, scnvector3

### Problem

I'd like the following function to return to me the world coordinates of a point handled by a tap gesture. I've properly implemented it (using a few online resources) to work with the center point of the frame, but I am having trouble shifting this point around the screen.

---

### Attempt

Here is the fully commented and working code for `getScreenCoordinates`, which returns a tuple containing (0) the direction vector of the screen coordinates and (1) the position vector of the screen coordinates. The issue is having this work with a point other than the center, passed in through the `screenCoord` parameter.

```
private func getScreenCoordinates(screenCoord:CGPoint) -> (SCNVector3, SCNVector3) { // (direction, position)
      if let frame = self.canvasView.session.currentFrame {
            let mat = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform) // 4x4 transform matrix describing camera in world space
            let direction = SCNVector3(-1 * mat.m31, -1 * mat.m32, -1 * mat.m33) // orientation of camera in world space
            let position = SCNVector3(mat.m41, mat.m42, mat.m43) // location of camera in world space

            return (dir, position)
      }
      return (SCNVector3(0, 0, -1), SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.2))
}
```

---

### Desired Solution

Provide a modified `getScreenCoordinates` function that returns the same data type, except instead of getting the world coordinates of the center point of the camera frame, it gets the world coordinates for `screenCoord`.

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding your question but are you trying to get an SCNVector3 from a CGPoint?

Comment: @JoshRobbins Basically, the expected behavior is that the user taps the screen, gets a CGPoint out of the tap location, and then the above function translates the point into a SCNVector3 with x and y values corresponding to the CGPoint and a z value that should be 0, if the solution is correct. It should get a position vector and a direction vector from this.

Answer (score -1):

maybe the code can help you.

```
// Get transform using ARCamera
func getCameraTransform(for camera: ARCamer) -> MDLTransform {
  return MDLTransform(transform: camera.transform)
}

// Intercept touch and place object 
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
  guard touch.tapCount == 1 else { return }

  guard let camera = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera else { return }
  let transform = getCameraTranform(for: camera)
  let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
  let cube = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
  let position = SCNVector3(
   transform.translation.x,
   transform.translation.y,
   transform.translation.z,
  )
  cube.position = position
  sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cube)
}
```

To see more detail, please see this post https://arvindravi.com/arkit-a-noobs-guide-part-three/